# How to Log Out from Stack Exchange

Tags: electrical

I just need to know how to log out of the site. I'll be back of course, but for now I need to log off, but can't find the button for that.

Comment: Go to top bar. Click far right icon.  At the top right of the drop-down menu, click "log out".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with home improvement

Answer (score -1):

top bar far right click on last icon
opens new window, log out

[image: log out]

[image: log out]